# Not getting expected results from SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this is my table

```
Field                   Type            Null    Key     Default  Extra
id_key                  int(11)         NO      PRI     NULL     auto_increment
tbl_users_username      varchar(255)    YES     UNI     NULL
tbl_users_password      varchar(32)     YES             NULL
tbl_users_identifier    varchar(32)     YES             NULL
tbl_users_token         varchar(32)     YES             NULL
tbl_users_access_type   int(1)          YES             NULL
tbl_users_timeout       int(10)         YES             NULL
```

this is my code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users where tbl_users_username = '$_POST[email_address]'" ;
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result)
{
    echo "TRUE";        
}
else
{
    echo "FALSE";
}
```

There are no problems connecting to the database.  The problem arises when I run the query.  No matter if the email is in the table or not it returns a $result.  What am I missing here?  It is supposed to echo true if email address exists in table, false if it is not in table.

Comment: Have you tried printing out $query to make sure it contains what you think it contains?

Comment: @andrewsi is right. First print out the query in order to see if you builded it correctly. It seems you need to concatenate your post as Sebas said in his answer.

Comment: if the email myemail@email.com $query = SELECT * FROM tbl_users where tbl_users_username = 'myemail@email.com'

Comment: Change `$result = mysql_query($query);` to `$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` and tell us what it says.

Comment: @WilliamMichaelVondran - Please accept any one of the answers you find acceptable below. This will help other SO users who come across your issue.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST[email_address]` should use single or double quotes i guess:

`$_POST["email_address"]` or `$_POST['email_address']`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users where tbl_users_username = '" . $_POST['email_address'] . "'" ;
```

However, as @FabioCosta says, you have to fetch the result or count the number of returned rows to achieve what you are aiming at:

```
$query = "SELECT 1 FROM tbl_users where tbl_users_username = '" . $_POST['email_address'] . "'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) === 1) {
    echo "TRUE";        
} else {
    echo "FALSE";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The result will be returned nevertheless(if you made a valid query) use [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-num-rows.php)  to check if the mail exists instead.
Actually use PDO if you can

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP's `mysql_num_rows` function, you should be able to return the number of rows, and your logic will work. So, try the following:

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num > 0) {
    echo "TRUE";
}else{
    echo "FALSE";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you print out your query to ascertain that it is 100% the query you expect it to be.

In addition to that, You are checking:

`$result = mysql_query($query);`

if($result)

This checks if a resource was returned from your query. It your query is **valid** then as per the [documentation](http://uk.php.net/mysql_query), you should always have a resource.

**Suggested code:**

`$result = mysql_query($query);`

```
if($result)
{
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($num > 0)
    {
        //do logic processing here...
        echo "TRUE"; 
    }
}
else
{
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

**Code Explanation:**

1. Fetch the resource from the query
2. If valid resource was returned, continue and check the number of records that were fetched
   from this query.
3. If the resource was not returned, the else part echo out a failure message.

I would **strongly suggest** that you look into using [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) library.

**Briefly the Advantages of PDO:**

1. Allows you to use prepared statement with ease (prepared statement are great for security!!!)
2. PDO can connect to various different Databases including MySQL, but others as well.
3. Its quite easy to use in my opinion and it quite easy to pick for new comers etc.

**Stack overflow usage tips:**

1. Always use the search in the top right hand corner. Numerous people have come across problems that may could help you.
2. Always have a look  at the [How to Ask Question FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)
3. Feedback & always ask further questions if required!

Answer (score 0):

The following query will select the tbl_users_username value based on the value in the posted email_address' value. So, use this query:

```
$query = 
"SELECT * FROM tbl_users where tbl_users_username = '".$_POST['email_address']."';";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT *
FROM tbl_users
WHERE tbl_users_username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email_address']) . "'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if($result)
{
    echo "TRUE";        
}
else
{
    echo "FALSE";
}
```

This should fix any problems you're running into, or at least give you a handy error message to work off of.